# Love does not envy or love is not jealous?

Tags: 1-corinthians

English Standard Version,
1 Corinthians 13:

> 4 Love is patient and kind; love does not **envy** or boast; it is not arrogant

NASB 1977:

> Love is patient, love is kind, and is not **jealous**; love does not brag and is not arrogant

Which translation is better?

Comment: KJV and Young's Literal both have 'envy'. There is nothing wrong with jealous love. God's love is a jealous love. Deuteronomy 4:24 _For the LORD thy God is a consuming fire, even a jealous God._

Answer (score 1):

The operative word in 1 Cor 13:9 is ζηλόω (zéloó which literally means "to boil" and gives our English word, "zealous" meaning to "seethe or boil").  This verb occurs 12 times in the NT: Acts 7:9, 17:5, 1 Cor 12:31, 13:4, 14:1, 14:39, 2 Cor 11:2, Gal 4:17(x2), 18, James 4:2, Rev 3:19.  BDAG gives the following meaning (Thayer gives very similar results):

1. **to be positively and intensely interested in something, *strive, desire, exert oneself earnestly, be dedicated***, eg, 1 Cor 12:31, 14:39, Gal 4:17ab, 2 Cor 11:2
2. **to have intense negative feelings over another's achievements or success, *be filled with jealously or envy toward someone***, eg, Acts 17:5, 1 Cor 13:4, James 4:2

Thus, "jealous" and envious" are both acceptable translations as they are, in English, almost exact synonyms.  Indeed, Meyer correctly observes:

> **οὐ ζηλοῖ** negation of all passionate, selfish feelings towards others (envy, jealousy, and such like)

The Jamieson-Fausset-Brown Bible Commentary succinctly observes:

> envieth—The Greek includes also jealousy

Answer (score 1):

Envy or Jealousy, though usually won't cause a confusion in context, actually they have a subtle difference in its perspective.

Envy is causing by the emotion, something you don't possess but you eager to have it.

Jealousy is causing by the emotion, something you possess but you feel threatened to lose it.

In 1 Cor 3:16, Paul used the Greek word "zéloó" (strong 2206), meaning

- an onomatopoetic word, imitating the sound of boiling water) – properly, to bubble over because so hot (boiling);
- (figuratively) "to burn with zeal" (J. Thayer);
- "to be deeply committed to something, with the implication of accompanying desire – 'to be earnest, to set one's heart on, to be completely intent upon' " (L & N, 1, 25.76). See 2205 (zēlos). (from biblehub.com)

So "zéloó" precisely covers both kind of feeling, it describes the unsettling of one's mind either "wanting love" or "losing love".

Either "Envy" or "Jealousy", though they have a difference, would not cause ambiguity to understanding the text. Instead, if it had to be translated to include both feelings, one word is not enough and it will spoil the simplicity and ease of reading.